# Upgrade to 1.9.3.6 results in getFallbackScheme() error

Tags: magento-1.9

I've upgraded Magento to 1.9.3.6 using Magento Connect and the "Mage_All_Latest" option. Upgrading from 1.8.1.0 BTW.

After the upgrade took I'm not able to reach both front- and backend. I get a blank page reading:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getFallbackScheme() on null in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 447
```

Now I understand that this could have something to do with an extension not being compatible with Magento 1.9 and I should disable modules to find out which one it is. However, I'm not able to reach my backend as well as my frontend. My question would be how to proceed since both front and backend are broken. Does it have anything to do with incompatible modules or I'm I simply wasting my time here as the upgrade itself has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some extension is not compatible with you version.
You can use ftp/ssh client, login to the server and disable extensions manually.
Go to `app/etc/modules/` directory and edit xml files:

```
<active>true</active>
```

change to

```
<active>false</active>
```

After doing this you should clear Magento’s cache.

After all modules are disabled try to enable it one by one.

> Note, that you need to disable only 3rd party extension. Leave Mage_
>   extensions as is.